# Is it possible to add dynamic content?

Tags: templates

I am looking into adding dynamic content to a pre created template mainly for Avery labels.

I searched online and there doesn't seem to be mention of  LaTeX being used to print to Avery Labels.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Welcome! No idea what you mean by 'dynamic content' but I always find the `labels` package works for me, whatever the brand of labels happens to be. (Not sure why this would matter, to be honest, but if you like Avery, I'm sure it'll work with those, too.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will! I am sure that people will be able to help you but you first need to explain more clearly what you want and preferably give some examples.

Comment: What's an Avery Label?

Comment: [The documentation for the `labels` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/labels/labels.pdf) is the first thing that popped up when I googled 'latex avery labels'.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Avery is a manufacturer (USA, I think) of self-adhesive labels, e.g. for envelopes, mail packages

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Definitely US. At least, they certainly make them for the US market. Maybe also other places. `labels` has out-of-the-box support for certain lines of Avery labels. How useful these are, I don't know. Even when I had Avery labels, I never had ones which were supported out of the box. But it is so easy to specify a custom layout that this really doesn't matter. You can configure the package for whatever labels you want (as long as they are basically equally sized rectangles arranged in a grid as is standard). But I don't know where the `dynamic content` comes in....

Comment: Avery also offers a free patch for Microsoft word to format text for all of their products.  These include CD-ROM labels, name badges, business cards, shipping labels for packages, etc.  I mostly use them for Christmas cards (I ruin too many envelopes by printing the wrong side or upside-down).

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example which merges a list of 8 names and addresses from a data file into a template which uses the `labels` package to create a list of address labels on an A4 sheet of 16 such labels. The merging is done with `textmerg`. 2 labels are created for each entry from the data file, for a total of 16 labels.

For convenience here, the data file is written using the `filecontents*` environment although, typically, this file would presumably be prepared separately.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
Jones
Dai
58A High Street\\Big City\\Small Country\\Earth\\Solar System\\Milky Way
Jones
Mari
64 Low Road\\Small Village\\Vast Country\\Earth\\Solar System\\Milky Way
Jones
Gwyn
57B High Street\\Big City\\Small Country\\Earth\\Solar System\\Milky Way
Jones
Gwen
6C Low Road\\Small Village\\Vast Country\\Earth\\Solar System\\Milky Way
Jones
Blod
78D High Street\\Big City\\Small Country\\Earth\\Solar System\\Milky Way
Jones
Tomos
98Q Low Road\\Small Village\\Vast Country\\Earth\\Solar System\\Milky Way
Jones
Ian
108V High Street\\Big City\\Small Country\\Earth\\Solar System\\Milky Way
Jones
Sioned
133 Low Road\\Small Village\\Vast Country\\Earth\\Solar System\\Milky Way
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=2
\LabelRows=8
\LeftPageMargin=4.5mm
\RightPageMargin=4.5mm
\TopPageMargin=13mm
\BottomPageMargin=13mm
\InterLabelColumn=2.5mm
\InterLabelRow=0mm
\RightLabelBorder=5mm
\LeftLabelBorder=5mm
\TopLabelBorder=5mm
\BottomLabelBorder=5mm

\begin{document}
% \LabelGridtrue        %turn on to line stuff up; off to process final version
\numberoflabels=2

\Fields{\cyfenw\enwaucyntaf\cyfeiriad\cyfenweto\enwaucyntafeto\cyfeiriadeto}

\Merge{\jobname.dat}{%

\genericlabel{%
        \begin{minipage}{90mm}
        \small\enwaucyntaf\ \cyfenw\\\cyfeiriad
        \end{minipage}
}
\genericlabel{%
        \begin{minipage}{90mm}
        \small\enwaucyntafeto\ \cyfenweto\\\cyfeiriadeto
        \end{minipage}
}}

\end{document}
```

[image: labels]

Comment: Jones is the most popular surname around these parts!

Comment: Apparently all Jones live in the Milky Way, but what about the Jones in the Andromeda Galaxy? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer They have not, so far, enrolled for one of my classes.