# Preserve label spacing dimensions when using mailmerge

Tags: spacing, sticky-labels, textmerg

I am making a sheet of address labels.
Here is my first iteration:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=4
\LabelRows=6
\LeftPageMargin=20mm
\RightPageMargin=20mm
\TopPageMargin=13mm
\BottomPageMargin=12.5mm
\InterLabelColumn=8mm
\InterLabelRow=5mm
\LeftLabelBorder=0.2mm
\RightLabelBorder=0.2mm
\TopLabelBorder=0.2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels
\LabelInfotrue % show info for labels

\begin{document}

\begin{labels}
A

B

C

D

E

F

G

H

I

J

K

L

M

N

O

P

Q

R

S

T

U

V

W

X
\end{labels}

\end{document}
```

Rather than manually writing all the labels in the body of the document, I wanted to store them in an external file. So I used the `textmerg` package, like in
[other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210885/how-to-print-addresses/)
[questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256928/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamic-content/).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{textmerg}

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=4
\LabelRows=6
\LeftPageMargin=20mm
\RightPageMargin=20mm
\TopPageMargin=13mm
\BottomPageMargin=12.5mm
\InterLabelColumn=8mm
\InterLabelRow=5mm
\LeftLabelBorder=0.2mm
\RightLabelBorder=0.2mm
\TopLabelBorder=0.2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels
\LabelInfotrue % show info for labels

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\Fields{\mylabel}

\Merge{\jobname.dat}{%
  \addresslabel{
    \mylabel
  }%
}%


\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the formatting has been disturbed in the switch. In particular, when I measure the column spacing with the Measure tool in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, it comes to about 9.5 mm instead of 8 mm. This is a serious problem when printing onto sticky labels.

Here is a comparison of the two:

[image: labels overlaid, red not matching black]

The original is in black, the second in red.

How can I iterate over an external file while keeping the original dimensions?

(If there is a way to use `textmerg` for this, I would be fine with that, but a method with, say, `datatool` or `catchfile` would be fine too.)

Here is a link to a Github repo to try it yourself if you're curious:

https://github.com/nbeaver/textmerg-labels-example

**Edit:** pull request has been [submitted](https://github.com/rf-latex/textmerg/pull/1) and [accepted](https://github.com/rf-latex/textmerg/commit/615c8d390b5d5462ca37e54173d1943d8f3db83a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a spurious space in the package's definition of `\ParseFields`. This is a bug and should be reported to the maintainer.

In the meanwhile, you can provide a corrected definition in the preamble.

```
\def\ParseFields#1{%
   \ifx#1\EndParseFields
      \let\NextParse\relax
   \else
      \let\NextParse\ParseFields
      \ifx#1+\DontAllowBlank
      \else
         \ifx#1-\AllowBlank
         \else\ReadIn#1% <= remove space here
         \fi
      \fi
   \fi\NextParse}
```

[image: non-spacey labels]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% without this I get A4
\usepackage{textmerg}

\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=4
\LabelRows=6
\LeftPageMargin=20mm
\RightPageMargin=20mm
\TopPageMargin=13mm
\BottomPageMargin=12.5mm
\InterLabelColumn=8mm
\InterLabelRow=5mm
\LeftLabelBorder=0.2mm
\RightLabelBorder=0.2mm
\TopLabelBorder=0.2mm
\BottomLabelBorder=0mm

\LabelGridtrue % show grid for labels
\LabelInfotrue % show info for labels

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents=\includegraphics{\jobname-a},scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1}

\def\ParseFields#1{%
   \ifx#1\EndParseFields
      \let\NextParse\relax
   \else
      \let\NextParse\ParseFields
      \ifx#1+\DontAllowBlank
      \else
         \ifx#1-\AllowBlank
         \else\ReadIn#1% <= remove space here
         \fi
      \fi
   \fi\NextParse}


\begin{document}
\Fields{\mylabel}%
\Merge{\jobname.dat}{%
  \addresslabel{%
    \mylabel
  }%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a typo: `letter` should be `letterpaper`. This should fix the paper size issue.

Comment: The \unskip fixes horizontal column spacing, but messes up vertical spacing. I don't mean to shift the goalposts, but I'm going to add a full sheet so it's more apparent.

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver Ah. Yes, I only looked at this example. Re. the paper: I'll still need `geometry` because `letterpaper` will only change the layout and not the paper size without it. (And the default paper size for me is A4, though for you it is probably US letter.)

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver Please see above. (Can't really call it an 'edit'. I just deleted the answer and wrote a new one.) Please report the bug to the maintainer and leave a note here when you do. (So that the maintainer doesn't get bombarded by people reporting the same bug.)

Comment: I can confirm that the fix works on my end. Sending a patch upstream is a commendable suggestion, but [both the maintainers for the textmerg package are listed as inactive](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textmerg), and I got a bounce off the only email address listed in the documentation.

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver Send it to the CTAN people in that case and include a link to this so they can tell what needs changing quickly. They may or may not do it, but they might.

Comment: textmerg has a new maintainer, so I sent a pull request here: https://github.com/rf-latex/textmerg/pull/1

Comment: more of a holding group than maintainers but it looks like a clear bug, thanks for the PR